# Looping a Web Scraping VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, macros

I'm trying to make a macro to scrape a table of fantasy football projections from ESPN.  I've got the code to work for scraping the data, but I haven't been able to figure out how to iterate through the various versions of the URL that I need to capture data from anything other than the first page.

The URL is: "http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&seasonTotals=true&seasonId=2016&slotCategoryId=0&startIndex=0"

I need to iterate the values for "slotCategoryID=0" and "startIndex=0".  Each time loading the webpage, copying the data, and appending it to a table in excel.

slotCategoryID represents the player position, and should iterate through the values 0,2,4,6,16,&17.

startIndex simply advances the page.  It's 0 for page 1, 40 for page 2, 80 for page 3, etc.

Please help!

Here is the code I have so far, which works to copy the data table once:

```
Sub extractTablesData()
'we define the essential variables

Dim IE As Object
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, t As Integer, pos As Integer
Dim elemCollection As Object


'----
        'add the "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference in your VBA Project indirectly
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")



        With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&seasonTotals=true&seasonId=2016&slotCategoryId=0&startIndex=0"

        ' we ensure that the web page downloads completely before we fill the form automatically
        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Wend

        ' again ensuring that the web page loads completely before we start scraping data
        Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

            For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
                For r = 1 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                    For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                    Next c
                Next r
            Next t

        End With
        ' cleaning up memory
        Set IE = Nothing

'----
End Sub
```

Comment: You said it:  you need to iterate.  So do that.  Update your `navigate` string with each iteration.  Or better yet, make the `extractTablesData` sub generic so you can pass in any URL, then do the iterating from a driving sub.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want!!

```
Sub Test()

   Dim ie As Object
   Dim i As Long
   Dim strText As String
   Dim doc As Object
   Dim hTable As Object
   Dim hBody As Object
   Dim hTR As Object
   Dim hTD As Object
   Dim tb As Object
   Dim bb As Object
   Dim tr As Object
   Dim td As Object

   Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet

     Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
     Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

     Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     ie.Visible = True

     y = 1   'Column A in Excel
     z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel
variable = 0
Here:

     ie.navigate "http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?&seasonTotals=true&seasonId=2016&slotCategoryId=0&startIndex=" & variable

     Do While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
     Do While ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

     Set doc = ie.document
     Set hTable = doc.getElementsByClassName("playerTableTable tableBody")

     For Each tb In hTable

        Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each bb In hBody

            Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tr In hTR

                 Set hTD = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                 y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                 For Each td In hTD
                   ws.Cells(z, y).Value = td.innerText
                   y = y + 1
                 Next td
                 DoEvents
                 z = z + 1
            Next tr
            Exit For
        Next bb
    Exit For
  Next tb

variable = variable + 40
GoTo Here:
End Sub
```